# C++: initialize reference to ofstream in initialization list

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, ofstream, initializer-list

I have read multiple questions and answers on that topic, but unfortunately none of them helped yet. I want to use the same debug file ouput in two classes A and B, where an instance of A creates an instance of B. I have something like:

```
class A {
public:
    A() : debug("debug.txt") { };
private:
    std::ofstream debug;
}

class B {
public:
    B(std::ofstream &ofs) : debug(ofs) { };
private:
    std::ofstream &debug;
}
```

and create an instance of it with

```
B *b = new B(debugUnderlying);
```

which works quite well. However, I now want to have an additional constructor to be able to use it without an ofstream. The object shall then open a new file. I got the point that, as I have a reference, I need to initialize it in the initialization list. I tried multiple things:

```
B() : debug() { debug.open("debug2.txt"); };

error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::ofstream& {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>&}’ from an rvalue of type ‘const char*’
```

or

```
B() : debug("debug2.txt") { };

error: value-initialization of reference type ‘std::ofstream& {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>&}’
```

or (quite clear, since I have a temporary object)

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::ofstream& {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>&}’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}’
```

How can I do this? Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: `B *b = new B(debugUnderlying);` stop programming as in Java

Comment: Can you specify what you mean? As you may have guessed, this is not the original code.

Comment: You don't have any reason to dynamically-allocate the `B` instance.

Comment: Never realized it. In fact, I actually learned Java before that. Thanks for the hint! (Although it shouldn't hurt to dynamically allocate, right?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may store a pointer and flag ownership:

```
class B {
   public:
   B() : stream(new ...), owner(true) {}
   B(std::ostream& s) : stream(&s), owner(false) {}
   ~B() { if(owner) delete stream; }
   private:
   std::ostream* stream;
   bool owner;
};
```

Note: I replaced ofstream with ostream.

Comment: This morks well after I realized I have to replace every `debug << "here" << std::endl;` with `*debug << "here" << std::endl;`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**to fix your error:**

```
B():debug(*(new std::ofstream("debug.txt"))){}
```

But: if you do so I guess you'll forget to delete...

**So:**

You better use a singleton to wrap the debug object

```
class Debug{
    std::ofstream debug;
    //private ctor, you can't create an object for this class outside
    Debug(const std::string& filename):debug(filename){}
public:
    //only way tou use this class is to call this method
    static Debug* Instance(){
            //the one and only Debug object, created at first use: 
        static Debug theObj("debug.txt");
        return &theObj;
    }
    //write method
    std::ostream& outstream(){
        return debug;
    }
};
//just for simplicity of use:
#define dbgout Debug::Instance()->outstream()
```

you can also define the macro like this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    #define dbgout Debug::Instance()->outstream()
#else
    // a release version won't create the debug file... 
    #define dbgout //
#endif
```

now you can use it like this from anywhere in your code:

```
dbgout<<" put your " << "stream " <<" here ";
```

Comment: The singleton is a dessign antipattern. It's only am awesome name for a global variable. It should be avoided whenever is possible.

Comment: Even if you use a singleton, you should never return a pointer, you should return a reference. In other words, don't give the user the control of your instance. What happens if the user deletes the instance?

Comment: deletion will failed since it is not dynamically allocated. and such a solution will make his life easy, so why not use it?

Comment: The user does not know if the pointer points to a dynamically-allocated chunk of memory or not.

Comment: he can see in the code. if you delete a pointer, and got segmentation fault, it mean you did something wrong.

Comment: We are dealing here in c++, and pointers usage is part of the language. you can take any variant and try to delete it's address, but I guess you won't do it, because you don't delete a pointer which you didn't allocate... you can do the following: int &x=*(new int); this is a reference you MUST delete! a pointer and a reference are quite the same. in JAVA, for example, there are no pointers and you delete references.

Comment: That is not the correct use of pointers. Pointers are used to represent ownership. You should read about smart pointers.